# how to use cherrpy built in data storage

Tags: python, cherrypy

Ok I have been reading the cherrypy documents for sometime and have not found a simple example yet.  Let say I have a simple hello world site, how do I store data?  Lets say I want to store a = 1, and b =2 to a dictionary using cherrypy.  The config files are confusing as hell.  Anyone have very simple example of storing values from a simple site in cherrypy?

Here is my code what am I doing wrong? I made a tmp file c:/tmp, where is the config file, and or where do I put it? This code worked before I try adding config?

```
import cherrypy
import os

cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.on': True,
 'tools.sessions.storage_type': "file",
 'tools.sessions.storage_path': "/tmp",
 'tools.sessions.timeout': 60})

class Application:

    def hello(self,what='Hello', who='world'):
        cherrypy.session['a'] = 1
        return '%s, %s!' % (what, who)

    hello.explose=True
root = Application()
cherrypy.quickstart(root)
```

Comment: I think you mean "hello.exposed = True".

Since you never read the session data, how do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your config file:

```
[/]
tools.sessions.on = True
tools.sessions.storage_type = "file" # leave blank for in-memory
tools.sessions.storage_path = "/home/site/sessions"
tools.sessions.timeout = 60
```

Setting data on a session:

```
cherrypy.session['fieldname'] = 'fieldvalue'
```

Getting data:

```
cherrypy.session.get('fieldname')
```

*Source: http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/CherryPySessions*

Answer (score 1):

You configure cherrypy to use sessions and store them to a file, e.g. in this way:

```
 cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.on': True,
     'tools.sessions.storage_type': "file",
     'tools.sessions.storage_path': "/tmp/cherrypy_mysessions",
     'tools.sessions.timeout': 60})
```

(or similarly in the config file of course), then `cherrypy.session` is the "per-user" dict you want, and `cherrypy.session['a'] = 1` and similarly for `'b'` is how you can store data there.